# Two dimensional char array from string using Stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream, chars

I am about to create the two dimensional array from string:

```
char[][] chars;
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

So the array will ilustrate this matrix:
[image]

But how can I do that using Java 8 Streams, cause I do not want to do this by casual loops ?

Comment: Why not just use loops? It will be so much clearer.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know that streams do not provide good readbility, but just want to do that using streams as a curosity.

Comment: Streams provide great readability... when used appropriately.

Comment: You can't do this elegantly with streams because there's unfortunately no `CharStream`.

Comment: Thank you guys, don't blame me for that. I just was interested how to that using Streams :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Poor loops. They get such a bad rap. I doubt a streams-based solution would be as clear as this:

```
int n = alphabet.length();
char[][] cs = new char[n][n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    cs[i][j] = alphabet.charAt((i + j) % n);
  }
}
```

If I had to do it with streams, I guess I'd do something like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, n)
    .forEach(
        i -> IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(j -> cs[i][j] = alphabet.charAt((i + j) % n)));
```

Or, if I didn't care about creating lots of intermediate strings:

```
cs = IntStream.range(0, n)
    .mapToObj(i -> alphabet.substring(i) + alphabet.substring(0, i))
    .map(String.toCharArray())
    .toArray(new char[n][]);
```

---

A slightly more fun way to do it:

```
char[][] cs = new char[n][];
cs[0] = alphabet.toCharArray();
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
  cs[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(cs[i-1], 1, n+1);
  cs[i][n-1] = cs[i-1][0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Stream.iterate()` to rotate each string incrementally and then convert them to `char` arrays:

```
chars = Stream.iterate(alphabet, str -> str.substring(1) + str.charAt(0))
        .limit(alphabet.length())
        .map(String::toCharArray)
        .toArray(char[][]::new);
```

Or you can rotate each string by its index, with Apache's [`StringUtils.rotate()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#rotate-java.lang.String-int-):

```
chars = IntStream.range(0, alphabet.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> StringUtils.rotate(alphabet, -i))
        .map(String::toCharArray)
        .toArray(char[][]::new);
```

Or with Guava's [`Chars`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html) utility class:

```
chars = Stream.generate(alphabet::toCharArray)
        .limit(alphabet.length())
        .toArray(char[][]::new);

IntStream.range(0, chars.length)
        .forEach(i -> Collections.rotate(Chars.asList(chars[i]), -i));
```